# tree render is not a function what does it mean I can't fix that

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, vercel

I'm trying to publish a project with Vercel, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
{"minifySvg": false }
```

This didn't work also:

```
module.exports = { "minifySvg":false }
```

What could be the problem?